# ¿Como declarar más de una función en un mismo namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespace

Quiero añadir varias funciones a un `namespace` en `JS`. Tengo un error cuando añado más de una función.

**Código:**

```
var xxx = {

    funcion_a: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_a()" );
    }

    funcion_b: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_b()" );
    }

} // fin / namespace
```

Falla en la declaración de la segunda función.

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Debes separar con comas (**,**) cada función del objeto `xxx`

Comment: Recuerda que namespaces en javascript es un patrón no es parte del lenguaje, por lo que no es más que un objeto común y corriente, en este caso con 2 propiedades: "funcion_a" y "funcion_b". Y como cualquier otro objeto sus propiedades se separan con ','

Answer (score 5):

Debes separar con comas (**,**) cada función del objeto `xxx`

```js
var xxx = {

    funcion_a: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_a()" );
    }, // Debes usar comas para separar cada función

    funcion_b: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_b()" );
    }

} // fin / namespace

xxx.funcion_a();
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema es que tienes que separar por comas ambas funciones:

```
var xxx = {

    funcion_a: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_a()" );
    }, //<-- Aquí faltaría la coma para separar la primera función de la segunda.

    funcion_b: function() {
        console.log( "usando f_b()" );
    }

}
```